# jQuery + координаты

Tags: jquery

Работаю с *mousedown, mousemove* для рисования выделения области в пределах блока. Ожидается, что действие будет возможно только при нажатой в пределах блока кнопке мыши (нажали - потянули).

Однако через раз рисование продолжается и после того, как кнопка мыши опущена. Хочется понять, что сделано не так.

[Исходники на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Persio/3DTbr/)

UPD1. Смущают также задержки при отрисовке прямоугольника.

Comment: Возможно потому, что мышь отжимается уже на #cover, а не на #field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить

```
$('#cover').mouseup(function(event){
    $('#field').unbind('mousemove');       
});
```

Т.к. кнопка мыши не всегда отжимается на **#field**

**UPD.** Если #cover засунуть внутрь #filed, можно убрать лишний обработчик и прямоугольник замечательно будет уменьшатьсяувеличиваться + никаких багов с отжатием кнопки.

Comment: Хотя не, та же печаль. Но вроде быстрее реагировать стало.

**UPD**. А если оставить оба обработчика, то все идеально. В зависимости от скорости мыши прямоугольник иногда не успевает обновиться и поэтому кнопка отжимается то на #field, то на #cover

Comment: Если оставить оба обработчика, то нельзя уменьшить прямоугольник.

Comment: @caravaneer Дык и до этого нельзя было =) Там в другом проблема:  mousemove выполняется только внутри #field, а #cover поверх него находится.

Если #cover засунуть внутрь #filed, можно убрать лишний обработчик и прямоугольник замечательно будет уменьшаться\увеличиваться + никаких багов с отжатием кнопки.